# How to use next with inject in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was writing some code like following:

```
[1,2,3,4,5].inject([]) do |res, a|
  res << a*a and next if a == 2
  res << a
end
```

It gives following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass
```

As by next it makes `res` variable as `nil`, How to work around this problem?

I tried various ways but couldn't get next to work with ruby, I know this snippet I have provided can be done without next(`a == 4 ? res << a*a : res << a`), but in my actual use-case I have some complex logic and can't be done that simply.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Replace the

```
res << a*a and next if a == 2
```

with

```
next res << a*a if a == 2
```

Now, it will work.

Example :-

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

ar = [1,2,3,4,5].inject([]) do |res, a|
  next res << a*a if a == 2
  res << a
end

p ar
# >> [1, 4, 3, 4, 5]
```

[Read the documentation of `next`](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-next)

> `next` can take a value, which will be the value returned for the current iteration of the block....

Answer (score 4):

Ugh. Don't use a trailing conditional for this. Instead it is easily done using a standard `if`/`else`:

```
[1,2,3,4,5].inject([]) do |res, a|
  if a == 2
    res << a*a
  else
    res << a
  end
end
# => [1, 4, 3, 4, 5]
```

Any time you feel like you're coding yourself into a corner, don't look for a way out, instead, back up and look at what you're trying to accomplish to see if there is a more straightforward way there.

I'd probably tweak the code a bit more though, for readability. Long term maintenance relies on quickly understanding what is going on, and code that is convoluted or not obvious can take its toll later:

```
[1,2,3,4,5].inject([]) do |res, a|
  if a == 2
    res << a*a
  else
    res << a
  end

  res # return it for clarity in what the block is returning
end
# => [1, 4, 3, 4, 5]
```

`inject` is similar to `each_with_object`, only it relies on the accumulator being returned at the end of the block, which is why I would add the `res` at the end of the block for clarity, due to the `if` block. Switching to `each_with_object` removes that reliance on the return value of the block, allowing the following code to be more logically clear:

```
[1,2,3,4,5].each_with_object([]) do |a, ary|
  if a == 2
    ary << a*a
  else
    ary << a
  end
end
# => [1, 4, 3, 4, 5]
```

Of course, at that point, the whole thing can be reduced further, and could take advantage of the ternary version using:

```
[1,2,3,4,5].each_with_object([]) do |a, ary|
  a2 = (a == 2) ? a * a : a
  ary << a2
end
# => [1, 4, 3, 4, 5]
```

Which of the above two are more readable is somewhat up to the person coding it and the person responsible for maintaining it. I'd lean toward the non-ternary version because it's more easily extended/expanded and doesn't have the line noise of the ternary `?:` chain.

---

Since it was asked in the comments, `map` reduces some noise, and is how we should transform an array:

```
[1,2,3,4,5].map { |a|
  (a == 2) ? a * a : a
}
```

That's untested but it looks correct.

Comment: I strongly agree. Beautiful answer.

Comment: @PatriceGahide Question was probably, why my `next` is not working ? :-) Not how to write it more better way..

Comment: I was making a point about looking past the immediate problem and finding the clearest solution. `map` would indeed have been the best, and fastest, path but `inject` and `each_with_object` work.

Comment: There is little point in literally answering a question when the resulting code is not a good programming practice. Using `next` might work, but is it the proper way to code for the solution? No. Instead, we are supposed to instruct and teach, so others can learn and pass on proper techniques. We need to teach others how to fish, we don't give them fish.

Comment: I knew that ternary/map can be used for the example I have given, but as I already stated, in my actual use-case I have some complex logic and can't be done that simply by map or ternary version.

Comment: @ArupRakshit Of course, and your answer beautifully addressed this specific issue ;) As for the rest, the Tin Man already answered. Again, I agree with him, but I missed the part where saurabh said that the logic was in fact more complex than that. I still suspect that the actual code could be written without this construct in a more readable way, but that question would surely overlap with http://codereview.stackexchange.com/